# Human Resources Information System in Sharepoint

Tags: list, lookup-column, people-picker

Is it possible to create a list from active directory users and make the list editable that syncs back to AD using User Profile service? I also want to add additional columns not in AD to the list. Not really sure where I could start with this.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using your **SharePoint profiles** to achieve your needs. In User Profile Service Application you can set any of your user profile properties to either "import from AD" or "export to AD". As well you can create properties which are not synced to or from Active Directory. **This is the easiest way!**

SharePoint user profiles are ready to be synced with Active Directory if you have been configurating your AD connection in User Profile Service Application (UPS).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full answer.  But perhaps this can get you started.  If you have already got data extracted from AD, perhaps you have it in a .csv file.  In Sharepoint you can create an external list (Add app).  (My screenshot is from SP 2013).

[image: Add App]

We have one or two things set up to extract data from other systems and bring it in to Sharepoint.  I believe powershell is used, in combination with a Task which Windows Task Scheduler runs.  It runs the script and updates the .csv file.

Next the .csv file is hooked up to the external Sharepoint list.

In turn, the external Sharepoint list is hooked up to a 'native' Sharepoint list.  The external lists have limited functionality and should be looked on as being a 'stepping stone' to getting your data in to Sharepoint.

As for looping back to refresh AD - I can't help with this part.  Hopefully this helps a little though.